# MYSQL: query the world database by join several tables

Tags: mysql, inner-join

> Give the SQL command to show for each country in North America:
>
> - The name of the capital city
> - The name of the country
> - The official language(s)
> - The percentage of people who speak the official language(s)
>
> The results should be alphabetical city name order, and within that by
> country name order, and within that by language order, and within that
> by ascending percentage.

Why do I get an error message not a unique table alias country?

```
SELECT
  city.name AS name, country.name AS name,
  countrylanguage.language, 
  countrylanguage.percentage
FROM country, countrylanguage, city
INNER JOIN country ON city.countrycode = country.code
INNER JOIN city ON country.capital = city.id
INNER JOIN countrylanguage on country.code = countrylanguage.countrycode
WHERE
  country.continent = 'North America' and
  countrylanguage.isofficial = 'T' and 
  country.capital = city.id
ORDER BY
  city.name ASC,
  country.name,
  country.language,
  countrylanguage.percentage ASC;
```

Comment: '. If you mix comma joins with the other join types when there is a join condition, an error of the form Unknown column 'col_name' in 'on clause....'' - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html - be warned.. AND why would you have both on the same tables?

Comment: BTW your error is because you are selecting all tables twice without using aliases to make them unique.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: What's your question about this? Can you share the full aned exat error message, and your attempts to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

The `FROM ... JOIN`  part of your query is incorrect. Try this.

```sql
SELECT
  city.name AS name, country.name AS name,
  countrylanguage.language, 
  countrylanguage.percentage
FROM country
INNER JOIN country ON city.countrycode = country.code
INNER JOIN city ON country.capital = city.id
INNER JOIN countrylanguage on country.code = countrylanguage.countrycode
WHERE
  country.continent = 'North America' and
  countrylanguage.isofficial = 'T' and 
  country.capital = city.id
ORDER BY
  city.name ASC,
  country.name ASC,
  country.language ASC,
  countrylanguage.percentage ASC;
```

When you say `FROM country, city, countrylanguage` it's the equivalent of the above code but with no `ON` clauses. It's the old-timey comma-join syntax (superseded in 1992 with explicit JOIN syntax).